# Batch File to compare 1 local and 1 network folder and copy local to another local if they match

Tags: if-statement, compare, robocopy, shared-directory, beyondcompare

I have a network folder that contains sub-folders and files on a network drive. I want to automate copying the files and folders to my 4 local computers. Due to bandwidth issues I have a scheduled task that pulls the update over at night to a single computer. I would like a batch file for the other 3 local computers that can verify when the 2 folders on separate devices (1 local and 1 remote) are in sync then copy the local files to itself.
I have looked through Robocopy, and several of the other compare commands and I see they give me a report of the differences, but what I am looking for is something conditional to continue batch processing. I would execute it from a scheduled task, but basically it would perform like:

**IF \remotepc\folder EQU \localpc1\folder" robocopy "\localpc1\folder" "c:\tasks\updater" /MIR
ELSE GOTO EOF**
Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A Beyond Compare script can compare two folders, then copy matching files to a third folder.

Script:

```
load c:\folder1 \\server1\share\folder1
expand all
select left.exact.files
copyto left path:base c:\output
```

To run the script, use the command line:

```
"c:\program files\beyond compare 4\bcompare.exe" "@c:\script.txt"
```

The @ character makes Beyond Compare run a file as a script instead of loading it for GUI comparison.

Beyond Compare scripting resources:

- [Beyond Compare Help - Scripting](https://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?scripts.html)
- [Beyond Compare Help - Scripting Reference](https://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?scripting_reference.html)
- [Beyond Compare Forums - Scripting](https://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/forum/beyond-compare-4-discussion/scripting-aa)

Comment: If the 2 folders do not match can it force them to match then copy to 3rd location?